# Why I'm getting this error "TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Tags: python, python-itertools

I need to print ['vanilla', 'chocolate sauce'], ['chocolate', 'chocolate sauce'] but I'm getting an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 15, in File "", line 10, in scoops
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Code Snippet is as follows:

```
  from itertools import combinations

class IceCreamMachine:
    
    def __init__(self, ingredients, toppings):
        self.ingredients = ingredients
        self.toppings = toppings
        
    def scoops(self):
        return list(combinations(self.ingredients,self.toppings))
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    machine = IceCreamMachine(["vanilla", "chocolate"], ["chocolate sauce"])
    print(machine.scoops()) #should print[['vanilla', 'chocolate sauce'], ['chocolate', 'chocolate sauce']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you were looking for `itertools.product`,

```
from itertools import product

class IceCreamMachine:
    
    def __init__(self, ingredients, toppings):
        self.ingredients = ingredients
        self.toppings = toppings
        
    def scoops(self):
        return list(product(self.ingredients, self.toppings))
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    machine = IceCreamMachine(["vanilla", "chocolate"], ["chocolate sauce"])
    print(machine.scoops()) #should print[['vanilla', 'chocolate sauce'],
```

Answer (score 1):

The `itertools.combinations()` method takes the second argument as an integer.
It generates all possible combinations of the iterable item passed in the first argument.
Read more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-itertools-combinations-function/)

For your problem, you can define the scoop function as

```
from itertools import product 
def scoop(self):
    return list(product(self.ingredients,self.toppings)))
```

Answer (score 1):

`combinations(list,r)` takes two arguments where **list** is Python List like [1,2,3] and **r** represents the length of each combination thus generated

Ex `combinations([1,2,3],2)` will generate

`[[1,2],[2,3],[1,3]]`

You are providing second argument as list which is wrong as it should be an **integer**

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [method signature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations): `combinations(iterable: Iterable, r: int)`.

The second argument (`self.toppings`) you pass doesn't match and results in a `TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

However, what you possibly want is to use `itertools.product`:

```
import itertools

def scoops(self):
    return list(itertools.product(self.ingredients, self.toppings))
```

Answer (score 1):

Combinations function definition is

```
combinations(iterable, r)
```

where iterable is list in your case and r is length of sequences therefore r should be integer

you should try

```
return list(combinations([self.ingredients, self.toppings]))
```